# Most effecient way of converting DataFrame to Matrix and vice versa

Tags: c++, dataframe, rcpp

I have been trying to implement some of the basic R functions like split in Rcpp for Data frames and matrices. For that I need to know the most efficient method of converting Data Frame  and Matrix back and forth. so far I use the DataFrame constructor to convert the matrix to DataFrame. How can I convert DataFrame Back to Matrix.Lets assume that all the data are of type double.

The current approach  is

matrix to DataFrame

```
NumericMatrix x;
DataFrame y= DataFrame(x);
y.attr("names")=x.attr("names");
```

DataFrame to Matrix

```
DataFrame x;
int xsize=x.size();
NumericVector col=x(0); 
NumericMatrix y(col.size(),xsize);
for(int i=0;i<xsize;i++){
    y(_,i)=col;
    if(i<xsize-1){
       col=x(i+1);
    }
}
y.attr("names")=x.attr("names");
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this conversion?

Also I am a newbie to Rcpp. Can Anybody explain how to find the source code of a particular class implementation, for example NumericMatrix?

Also the last line

```
y.attr("names")=x.attr("names")
```

does not set the column names of x as column names of y. Can anybody explain how to set the column names as the column names of the data frame.

Comment: I think you have to columns by column as you do. And don't use the i+1 offset: both start their index at zero in C++.

Comment: Thank you I uesd the offset since I took out the first column before the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `nrow` method for `DataFrame`. This could simplify your code. You don't need the special casing for the first column, etc ...

```
int xsize=x.size();
NumericMatrix y(x.nrows(),xsize);
for(int i=0;i<xsize;i++){
    y(_,i) = NumericVector(x[i]);
}
```

As for setting the column names, you can go through the `dimnames` attributes:

```
y.attr("dimnames") = List::create( R_NilValue, x.attr("names") ) ;
```

The source code for `Matrix` is [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/vector/Matrix.h) but I'm not sure this is going to help you.